# Samsung SSSP device browser debugging

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, tizen

Is there any way to get some sort of developer console for the browser on a Samsung SSSP device? I have both a 10" and 32" device, but I can't seem to find any way to "debug" the browser. I'd like to have something like Firebug or the Chrome developer console where I can inspect the various elements and figure out why things are looking the way they look and not formatting like I would expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

Use weinre. 
https://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/Home.html
Just include the script tag with a script and it will give you Chrome like console. You can run Javascript remotely on the device.